# How can I crawl a webPage which through javascript dynamically generated like this

Tags: java, javascript, https, webdriver, web-crawler

[image: The Javascript code which can get remain time]

I hava crawl the webPageSource by use the selenium and the code  like this

```
public static String getCurrentPageSource(String url) {
    webDriver = new ChromeDriver();

    webDriver.get(url);

    String src = webDriver.getPageSource();

    //writeInfile(src);
    webDriver.close();

    return src;
}
```

but I can't see the remain time in the pageSource I have crawl Because it is dynamically generated by JS.

Comment: I'm not able to understand the issue. Are you talking about web-scraping or crawling?

Comment: I am learnning the Crawling now. And want to get remainTime in the webPageSource which dynamically  generated by JS. In my mind, crawling is one part of web-scraping.

Comment: If possible can you share the page url you are dealing with? Its difficult to deal with this without trying out the code. Also, see this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10074466/reading-dynamic-web-page-content-in-java